# How do i calculate change between values in vector? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector

i’m trying to subtract the first value in a vector with the 4th value in the same vector (4th with the 8th value and so on) but i can’t get it to work. I would like it to be a vector with 57 values in the end.

i’m trying to use a for loop, but it seems to be totaly wrong.

any suggestions how to solv it

Comment: Subtract "_with_"?
`1`,`4`,`8` doesn't quite make a logical sequence, does it?
Have you tried something like `x(4:3:end) - x(1:3:end-3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it should be avoided the use of for loops in matlab whenever possible. In this case it is fairly easy to achieve what you are trying to do (if I understood the question correctly).
If you want as output a vector that has in each component the difference of two components of the original vector, this is a way to do it:

`b = a(indices_1) - a(indices_2);`

where a is the original vector and `indices_1`and `indices_2` are vectors holding the indices that you want to extract from a. In your case, I do not quite get what these indices may be. Probably, you need to do something like `indices_1 = 1:3:length(a)` and `indices_2 = 4:3:length(a)`, but you should be more precise.

As an advice for the next question that you will post, please provide some sample code. It is self explanatory and also proofs that you at least tried to tackle the problem.